# PHP code displays as text

Tags: php, html

I am certain that my code is correct, and before you say the file is called whatever.html I am positive that it is a .php
It displays ALL of my code, and not starting from a specific point, oh and btw PHP works on other pages of mine. So PHP is installed
Here is my code:

```
    <?
include("include/session.php");
  $ASID  = $_GET['id'];
  $BOATNAME  = $_GET['moorings'];
 $LoginName = 'Log in';
 if($session->logged_in){
 $LoginName = 'Account Center';
 }
 $con = mysql_connect("********","******","*************2");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  mysql_select_db("****", $con);
$query = "select * from **** where **** like '$ASID' AND BoatName like '$BOATNAME'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Couldn't execute query");
while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $MooringList = $row["MooringList"];
  $MooringList2 = $row["MooringList2"];
  $Number = $row["Number"];
  $Latitude = $row["Latitude"];
  $Latitude2 = $row["Latitude2"];
  $Latitude3 = $row["Latitude3"];
  $Longitude = $row["Longitude"];
  $Longitude2 = $row["Longitude2"];
  $Longitude3 = $row["Longitude3"];
  $Schedule = $row["Schedule"];
  $ScheduleCD = $row["ScheduleCD"];
  $MoorLengthFT = $row["MoorLengthFT"];
  $MoorLengthMtrs = $row["MoorLengthMTRS"];
  $MoorTonnage = $row["MoorTonnage"];
  $Layer = $row["Layer"];
  $BoatName = $row["BoatName"];
  $BoatType = $row["BoatType"];
  $BoatLengthFT = $row["BoatLengthFT"];
  $BoatLengthMTRS = $row["BoatLengthMTRS"];
  $BoatInsurance = $row["BoatInsurance"];  
}  
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>**** - Add Mooring</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script language="javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myform").validate({
            debug: false,
            rules: {
                     Number:"required"                  
            },
            messages: { 
                  Number:"* The number can't be blank"  
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                // do other stuff for a valid form
                $.post('addMooringScript.php', $("#myform").serialize(), function(data) {       
                    $('#result').html(data);
                });
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    <style>
    label.error { width: 250px; display: inline; color: red;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
<h1>******</h1>
<div id="loginDetails">
<? include('loggedInTopStatus.php'); ?>
</div>
</div>
<div class="content"><br />
<div id="news">
<div id="right">
<form name="myform" id="myform" action="" method="POST">  
<h2>Moorings - Add</h2>
<div id="result"></div>
<table width = "2000" border="0">
<tr width="1000">
<input type="hidden" name="AssignedTo" value ="<? $_POST['id'] ?> "/>
<tr>
<td width="50px">Mooring List: </td>
<td>
 <input type="text" name="MooringList" size="5" value="<? echo $MooringList; ?>" />
  <input type="text" name="MooringList2" size="20" value="<? echo $MooringList2; ?>" />
</tr></td>
<tr><td width="50px">Number: </td><td><input type="text" name="Number" maxlength="30" value="<? echo $Number ?>"></td></td>
<tr><td width="50px">Latitude: </td><td>
  <input type="text" name="Latitude" size="3" value="<? echo $Latitude; ?>" />O
  <input type="text" name="Latitude2" size="3" value="<? echo $Latitude2; ?>" />' .
  <input type="text" name="Latitude3" size="5" value="<? echo $Latitude3; ?>" />
</tr></td>
<tr><td width="50px">Longitude: </td><td>
  <input type="text" name="Longitude" size="3" value="<? echo $Longitude; ?>" />O
  <input type="text" name="Longitude2" size="3" value="<? echo $Longitude2; ?>" />' .
  <input type="text" name="Longitude3" size="5" value="<? echo $Longitude3; ?>" />
</tr></td>
<tr><td width="50px">Schedule: </td><td>
<input type="text" name="Schedule" size="3" /> CD 
  <input type="text" name="ScheduleMtrs" size="3" /> Mtrs
</tr></td>
<tr><td width="50px">Moor Length: </td><td>
  <input type="text" name="Moorlength" size="3" /> FT 
  <input type="text" name="MoorlengthMtrs" size="3" /> Mtrs
</tr></td>
 <tr><td width="50px">Moor Tonnage: </td><td>
  <input type="text" name="MoorTonnage" size="4" /> 
</tr></td>
 <tr><td width="50px">Layer: </td><td>
   <input type="text" name="Layer" size="8" /> 
</tr></td>
 <tr><td width="50px">Boat Name: </td><td>
   <input type="text" name="BoatName" size="15" />
   <input type="radio" name="BoatType" value="Leisure" /><b> Leisure  </b>
</tr></td>
     <tr><td width="50px">Type: </td><td>
   <input type="text" name="Type" size="15" />
   <input type="radio" name="BoatType" value="Commercial" /> <b>Commercial  </b>
</tr></td>
     <tr><td width="50px">Length: </td><td>
   <input type="text" name="LengthFt" size="8" />Ft
   <input type="text" name="LengthMtrs" size="8" />Mtrs   
</tr></td>
     <tr><td width="50px">Insurance: </td><td>
   <input type="text" name="Insurance" size="18" />
</tr></td>
</tr>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<? echo $_GET['id']; ?>" />
<tr><td><input type="submit" value="Edit Mooring" />   </tr></td>
</table>
</form>
</div>
<div class="left">
<? include('sitemenu.php'); ?>
</div>
<br />

<div id="footer">
<a href="#">&copy; 2010 *****</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, I have filtered it where nessasary

Comment: Have you tried using <?php ?> as your php tags instead of <? ?> ? I know that was a problem I've had before.

Comment: You using Dreamweaver or a another similar program?

Comment: Similar EnginSite Editor for PHP

Comment: Did you entered that code in some sort of WYSIWYG control than saved the file ? If so it could be very likely that all your text was HTML encoded and is simply displayed.

Comment: I am running my server in localhost, using IIS, MySql and PHP ofcourse. I did not use WYSIWYG either, I started from scratch from a plain PHP file.

Comment: Did you check for errors at your iis/php logs?

Comment: No, but I wouldn't suspect this as an error if it didnt return a 500 error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<?php` on the beginning.

Comment: Replace ALL <? with <?php and it will work, I just tested on your code.

Comment: The thing I use is EnginSite Editor for PHP

Comment: Then check the permissions, make sure they are 644.

Comment: Tried, but still nothing. The permissions of the working PHP pages are the same as the non-functional one

Comment: This is weird, I got the same "effect" with your code then I replaced all <? with <?php and worked fine. Are you sure you replaced all the tags?

Comment: Yes, I even searched for all <? and it returned only <?php

Answer (score 3):

You have disabled short_open_tags in your php.ini, right? Then you have to start blocks of PHP code with `<?php`, not just `<?`.

Comment: Still doesnt work, and was used previously on other functional pages.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the short-tags are disabled. Try using `<?php` instead of just `<?`

Comment: <? was used in other pages of mine without fail and Other PHP pages in the same directory work correctly

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for replying to a very old post but I had exactly the same problem so my solution might help someone.

In my case it was an ID-ten-T problem.

I had two copies of the inserted code in two folders under identical names (I had set up an 'inserts' folder, copied the files across but failed to delete all the originals.  So the code was including the original file but I was editing the copy.  And the original didn't have the

ID-ten-T, for those who haven't come across it before, is sometimes written ID10T